# two images headers doesn't appear and footers

Tags: graphics, formatting, header-footer, fancyhdr

I want to make this template in LaTex with the two logos on either side of the header and the little footer that you can see in the example, however, I tried with fancyhdr and set a new style page or placed the images alone, but nothing happend.

example i want to achieve:
[image]

my progress:
[image]

my code:

```
\documentclass[11pt,letter,twoside,twocolumn]{article}
%SIZES AND MARGINS 
\special{papersize=8.5in,11in}
\usepackage[paperheight=27.94cm,paperwidth=21.59cm,top=1.69cm,bottom=3cm,inner=1.99cm,outer=2.74cm]{geometry}
 % fancy headers/footers

\usepackage{fancyhdr,color}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\chead{\footnotesize{Author/ Revista DYNA, 87(213), pp. 148-158, April - June, 2021}}
\lhead{}
\rhead{}
\cfoot{\footnotesize\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\setlength{\voffset}{-10mm}                        
\setlength{\topmargin}{0mm}
\setlength{\headheight}{5mm}
\setlength{\headsep}{5mm}
\setlength{\footskip}{10mm}


%for the numbers date's
\usepackage[super]{nth}


%LANGUAGES
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,]{babel}  % Idiomas add %spanish,es-noshorthands
\usepackage{titling}
\usepackage{setspace}

%MATH
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\usepackage{authblk}
% para poder introducir varias figuras que ocupen el ancho de las dos columnas.
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{graphicx}

% for dummy text
\usepackage{lipsum}


%------------ TITLE-------------------------------%
\setstretch{1.0}
\title{\LARGE\textbf{State of stress in the main shaft of a coffee pulper machine\vspace*{-12pt}}}

\author[a]{Valentina Mejía Gallón}
\author[a]{Sebastián Gómez Duran}
\author[a]{Andrés Felipe Jaramillo}
\author[a]{Simón González Zapata}
\affil[a]{\footnotesize{\textit{Facultad de Minas, Universidad Nacional de Colombia, Medellín, Colombia, vamejiag@unal.edu.co, mprada@unal.edu.co, mprada@unal.edu.co, mprada@unal.edu.co}}}

\renewcommand\Authands{ \& } % change "and" for &
\date{\vspace*{-60pt}}


%------------ MAIN DOCUMENT------------------------------------%
\begin{document}
\setcounter{page}{1}
\twocolumn[
\begin{@twocolumnfalse}
\begin{titlingpage}

\maketitle
\end{titlingpage}

\begin{center}
\scriptsize{Received: July \nth{10}, 2021. Received in revised form: August \nth{3}, 2021. Accepted: November \nth{25}, 2021.}\vspace*{5pt}
\end{center}
%-----ABSTRACT-----%

\footnotesize\textbf{Abstract}

\footnotesize{This is an example of an article formatted for our journal. Note that this text is typed in Times New Roman, size 9, justified, with the word Abstract in bold, Type title and in a separate line. Abstract length does not exceed 150 words. Also, note that keywords are separated by semicolon.}

\vspace{1\baselineskip}
\textit{Keywords}: manuscript formatting; camera$-$ready manuscript.
\vspace{0.2cm}
\par\noindent\rule{\textwidth}{0.4pt}
\vspace{0.05cm}
%------SECOND TITLE -------------%
\begin{titlepage}
\centering
\setstretch{1.5}
{\LARGE\textbf{Estado de esfuerzos en eje principal de una despulpadora de café}}

\end{titlepage}

%-----ABSTRACT 2-----%
\vspace{2\baselineskip}
\footnotesize\textbf{Resumen}

\footnotesize{This is an example of an article formatted for our journal. Note that this text is typed in Times New Roman, size 9, justified, with the word Abstract in bold, Type title and in a separate line. Abstract length does not exceed 150 words. Also, note that keywords are separated by semicolon.}

\vspace{1\baselineskip}
\textit{Palabras clave}: manuscript formatting; camera$-$ready manuscript.
\vspace{0.2cm}
\par\noindent\rule{\textwidth}{0.4pt}
\vspace{0.1cm}
\end{@twocolumnfalse}
]

%---------INTRODUCTION--------------------%
\newpage
\section{Introduction}
\lipsum[1-8]
\end{document}}
```

Answer (score 1):

A few observations:

- You could define a special pagestyle for  the first page (I assume that you want this header only on the first page). You can do this with `\fancypagestyle`. But it would require to have a different `\headheight` on this page, different from the other pages. It can be done, but it is tricky. Therefore I advise to put this header in the normal text body, and put an empty real header on that page (with a special page style). That is what I do in my solution.
- You define various page parameters with `\setlength`, but it is much better to do this with the `geometry` parameters. Otherwise you use two different mechanisms which may cause conflicts. The same is true for `\special{papersize=8.5in,11in}`. This is what `geometry` will do for you. So I commented these out.
- I put the whole optional parameter of `\twocolumn` in braces `{}` so that square brackets can be used inside it.

That take into account, he is my solution:

```
\documentclass[11pt,twoside,twocolumn]{article}
%SIZES AND MARGINS 
%\special{papersize=8.5in,11in}
\usepackage[paperheight=27.94cm,paperwidth=21.59cm,top=1.69cm,bottom=3cm,inner=1.99cm,outer=2.74cm]{geometry}
 % fancy headers/footers

\usepackage{fancyhdr,color}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\chead{\footnotesize{Author/ Revista DYNA, 87(213), pp. 148-158, April - June, 2021}}
\lhead{}
\rhead{}
\cfoot{\footnotesize \copyright\ The author: licensee ...\\Revista DYNA ...\\DOI: http://...}
\fancypagestyle{firstpage}{%
  \fancyhead{}
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
}

% \setlength{\voffset}{-10mm}                        
% \setlength{\topmargin}{0mm}
% \setlength{\headheight}{5mm}
% \setlength{\headsep}{5mm}
% \setlength{\footskip}{10mm}


%for the numbers date's
\usepackage[super]{nth}


%LANGUAGES
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,]{babel}  % Idiomas add %spanish,es-noshorthands
\usepackage{titling}
\usepackage{setspace}

%MATH
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\usepackage{authblk}
% para poder introducir varias figuras que ocupen el ancho de las dos columnas.
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{graphicx}

% for dummy text
\usepackage{lipsum}


%------------ TITLE-------------------------------%
\setstretch{1.0}
\title{\LARGE\textbf{State of stress in the main shaft of a coffee pulper machine\vspace*{-12pt}}}

\author[a]{Valentina Mejía Gallón}
\author[a]{Sebastián Gómez Duran}
\author[a]{Andrés Felipe Jaramillo}
\author[a]{Simón González Zapata}
\affil[a]{\footnotesize{\textit{Facultad de Minas, Universidad Nacional de Colombia, Medellín, Colombia, vamejiag@unal.edu.co, mprada@unal.edu.co, mprada@unal.edu.co, mprada@unal.edu.co}}}

\renewcommand\Authands{ \& } % change "and" for &
\date{\vspace*{-60pt}}


%------------ MAIN DOCUMENT------------------------------------%
\begin{document}
\setcounter{page}{1}
\twocolumn[{
\begin{@twocolumnfalse}
\noindent\makebox[\textwidth]{\includegraphics[height=2cm]{example-image-a} \hfill 
\includegraphics[height=2cm]{example-image-b}}\\\rule[8pt]{\textwidth}{1pt}
\vspace{-2cm}
\begin{titlingpage}

\maketitle
\end{titlingpage}

\begin{center}
\scriptsize{Received: July \nth{10}, 2021. Received in revised form: August \nth{3}, 2021. Accepted: November \nth{25}, 2021.}\vspace*{5pt}
\end{center}
%-----ABSTRACT-----%

\footnotesize\textbf{Abstract}

\footnotesize{This is an example of an article formatted for our journal. Note that this text is typed in Times New Roman, size 9, justified, with the word Abstract in bold, Type title and in a separate line. Abstract length does not exceed 150 words. Also, note that keywords are separated by semicolon.}

\vspace{1\baselineskip}
\textit{Keywords}: manuscript formatting; camera$-$ready manuscript.
\vspace{0.2cm}
\par\noindent\rule{\textwidth}{0.4pt}
\vspace{0.05cm}
%------SECOND TITLE -------------%
\begin{titlepage}
\centering
\setstretch{1.5}
{\LARGE\textbf{Estado de esfuerzos en eje principal de una despulpadora de café}}

\end{titlepage}
\thispagestyle{firstpage}

%-----ABSTRACT 2-----%
\vspace{2\baselineskip}
\footnotesize\textbf{Resumen}

\footnotesize{This is an example of an article formatted for our journal. Note that this text is typed in Times New Roman, size 9, justified, with the word Abstract in bold, Type title and in a separate line. Abstract length does not exceed 150 words. Also, note that keywords are separated by semicolon.}

\vspace{1\baselineskip}
\textit{Palabras clave}: manuscript formatting; camera$-$ready manuscript.
\vspace{0.2cm}
\par\noindent\rule{\textwidth}{0.4pt}
\vspace{0.1cm}
\end{@twocolumnfalse}
}]

%---------INTRODUCTION--------------------%
\newpage
\section{Introduction}
\lipsum[1-8]
\end{document}}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! It did work :)